# Ant build.xml: referring to path id in a target condition

Tags: ant, build

Using ant, in my build.xml I have:

```
<path id="build.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${maven.repo.local}/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.6.10.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar"/>
    .
    .
    .
   <pathelement location="${maven.repo.local}/com/h2database/h2/1.3.174/h2-1.3.174.jar"/>
</path>
```

which I use as refId in the classpath compile target. Another target checks if the libs are already present otherwise they will be downloaded:

```
 <target name="checkLibs">
    <condition property="present">
       <and>
             <pathelement location="${maven.repo.local}/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.6.10.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar"/>
             .
             .
             .
             <pathelement location="${maven.repo.local}/com/h2database/h2/1.3.174/h2-1.3.174.jar"/> 
       </and>
    </condition>
 </target>
```

Is there a way to refer in my checkLibs target to the path structure defined before without having to list all the libs again in the and nested condition?

Thanks

Comment: Much better solution is to use Apache ivy or the Maven ANT task. I would personally recommend ivy (more flexible) but the Maven task will be able to share the Maven local repo. In both cases you are using a dedicated dependency manager for your ANT build instead of relying on luck to ensure the right jar is present.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor this comment is not helping in responding to the question, is just suggesting another way to do it. Anyhow I do not understand your mean of "luck" while looking for the jars, if they are there is ok, otherwise they will be downloaded :\

Comment: @LMG The user is constructing a fixed path to a file directory structure that is populated by Maven. By "luck" I mean difficulties that might be later experienced should someone attempt to run the build on another machine, or if someone purges the local Maven repository (something that is remarkably common). In conclusion my  suggestion to use ivy is well meaning because it looks like the user is already using Maven.